# Apply on Dataframe returning all None

Tags: python, pandas, apply, series

I am trying to multiply the values of a column by 12 if that row/column isn't `None`.

I have tried:

```
def length_inches(x):
    if x is not None:
        int(x)*12

df['LENGTH'] = df['LENGTH'].notnull().apply(length_inches)
```

And I have tried:

```
def length_inches(x):
    int(x)*12

df['LENGTH'] = df['LENGTH'].notnull().apply(length_inches)
```

But it's returning all `None` in the Length column.

Here is my dataframe:

```
                                          DESCRIPTION  LENGTH  WIDTH   GAUGE  \
0   STRETCH FILM BENCHMARK GREEN   28.5" X 10000' ...   10000  28.5      51    
1   STRETCH FILM TORQUE            16X1500 4RL/CS ...    1500    16    31.5    
2   STRETCH FILM TORQUE            16X1500 4RL/CS ...    1500    16    31.5    
3   STRETCH FILM TORQUE            16X1500 4RL/CS ...    1500    16    31.5    
4   STRETCH FILM BENCHMARK OPTIMUM 30 X 7500'  20R...    7500    30      61    
5   STRETCH FILM TORQUE            16X1500 4RL/CS ...    1500    16    31.5    
6   STRETCH FILM TORQUE            16X1500 4RL/CS ...    1500    16    31.5    
7   STRETCH FILM BENCHMARK OPTIMUM 20" X 7500'  40...    None   None    None
```

How can I account for the `None`'s in this dataframe and still run the calculation over `df['LENGTH']`

The type of that series is `LENGTH  object`

If that row is `None` I would like to just `pass`.

Comment: What type is your series? i.e. `print(df.dtypes)`. What do you want to do if your value is `None`?

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df.LENGTH.replace('None',np.nan))*12` apply is kind of redundant here

Comment: you should be able to just do `df.loc[df['LENGTH'].notnull(), 'LENGTH'] *=12`

Comment: May be you need: `df['LENGTH'].apply(length_inches)` and a return statement in your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) outputs a Boolean series depending on whether your series is null. It doesn't filter a series for non-null values. In fact, this explicit filtering is not necessary. You should use vectorised calculations, as described below, when working with numeric data in Pandas.

There are likely only a couple of scenarios you need to consider:

#### 1. float series => no conversion

If your series is `float`, i.e. `df['LENGTH'].dtype` returns a `float` type, don't perform any conversion or checking. Just use:

```
df['LENGTH'] *= 12
```

#### 2. object series => use pd.to_numeric

If your series is `object` type, convert it to `float` first:

```
df['LENGTH'] = pd.to_numeric(df['LENGTH'], errors='coerce')
df['LENGTH'] *= 12
```

[`pd.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a custom function, on the other hand, is not vectorised: internally, it's just a thinly veiled loop. Avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @jppThanks so much for this simple answer and explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You din't `return` anything from your functions (you `return`ed *None*):

```
def length_inches(x):
    if x is not None:
        return int(x)*12
    else:
        return None

df['LENGTH'].apply(length_inches)
```

Comment: and then `df['LENGTH'].apply(length_inches)`? I suppose.

Comment: The best answer to date, simply return the values in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You must return a value at the end of your function.

Try:

```
def length_inches(x):
    if x is not None:
         return int(x)*12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 df['LENGTH']=df['LENGTH'].replace('None',0).astype(int)*12
```